# How does SystemVerilog compiler knows to separate two arguments in a macro?

Tags: macros, system-verilog

I have this macro:

```
`define do_code(DO_SOETHING, ID) \
    fork \
       begin \
          ``DO_SOMETHING`` \
       end \
       begin \
          $display("%s",ID.name()); \
       end \
    join_any \
    disable fork; \
```

and I use it as such:

```
`do_code($display("%s",argA.name()), argB)
```

How does the compiler knows to separate the two macro's input arguments correct:

```
DO_SOMETHING = $display("%s",argA.name())
ID = argB
```

Why not break it to:

```
DO_SOMETHING = $display("%s"
ID = argA.name()), argB
```

???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler knows because the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595)
says in section *22.5.1 `define*

> Actual arguments and defaults shall not contain comma or
> right parenthesis characters outside matched pairs of left and right parentheses (), square brackets [],
> braces {}, double quotes "", or an escaped identifier.

The comma in your fist argument is inside a matched pair of parenthesis.

BTW, you should not be using ``` `` ``` unless you are trying to create a new identifier by joining macro argument with text in the body of the macro,